# grid fixed gap between rows when there are not enough items?

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

Hello i'm having this problem where if i don't have enough items there is more space between them than the row gap i provided? Why is that happening? (i have the same issue when i put flex-wrap:wrap......

This is what i have on the container

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 400px));
grid-template-rows: 100px;
grid-column-gap: 10px;
grid-row-gap: 10px;
justify-content: center;
height: calc(100% - 204px);
padding: 10px 10px 60px 10px;
```

On the items

```
height: 100px;
cursor:pointer;
width:100%;
border-radius: 0.75rem;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3g2h.png

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`grid-template-rows: 100px;` means that the first row will be `100px` and all the other will have an auto height. Either remove the property or use `grid-auto-rows: 100px;` to make sure **all** the rows will behave the same